# Share object from in local package

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I've created an application which is working as expected.

My application structure is like following:

```
myproj
   Gopkg.toml
   Gopkg.lock
   src
      server
         main.go
      utils
          file1.go
          logger.go
      handler
          handler1.go
          handler2.go
```

Now inside the main.go file I've created a logger like the following:

File `server-> main.go`

```
import (
      "handler"
      "utils"
      "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var logger                *logrus.Logger

fun init(){
    logger = utils.InitLogs()
} 


func main(){
  logger.info("my message")

  …

  handler.run()

}
```

Everything is **working** as expected!

Now I want to use the logger inside the `handler1&2` files (from diff package inside my local project)

To do this, I did the following steps.
Inside the handler `init` the logger (exactly as I did in the main file) and it’s working

File `handler-> handler1.go`

```
import (
      "utils"
      "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var logger                *logrus.Logger

fun init(){
   //Init the logger again
    logger = utils.InitLogs()
} 
func run(){
   //here Im not using logger otherwise maybe I can move it as parameter…
} 

func build(){
  //Here Im using the logger
  logger.info("Hi") 
}
```

While this is working but I've created **two** instance of logger, *first* on `main` and **second** on `handler1` which Im not sure is best

> My questions are:

1. I want to reuse the `logger` inside the `handler` class/module, is a better way to do it in Go?

This is **diff package** (inside my local proj)  and I'm not sure that I'm that if Im **not re-use the same logger object** from the `main` method, this is the right way to do it...

2. (lower prio question) Is my project structure okay for Go? I used [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) as reference which is similar...[also this](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) which is a bit different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to share your logger instance across your project, one way is to just export it as a global variable from your utils package as Armin suggested in his answer:

```
package utils

...

var Logger *logrus.Logger

func init() {
    Logger = InitLogs()
}
```

I'd bet you can then get away with not having to export `InitLogs()` by changing it to `initLogs()`

Then, elsewhere in your code, you can import `utils` and use that logger instance:

```
import "utils"

...
func something() {
    utils.Logger.Info("Hi")
}
```

Alternatively, if it makes sense to keep all your configuration in one place, you can declare your logger pointer as a field of a config struct and initialize it along with the rest of your program configuration (if you have any).

For example, say you have the following in your `utils` package:

```
package utils

...

type MyAppConfig struct {
    // whatever config parameters your app needs,
    // like DB connections, etc.
    Logger *logrus.Logger
}

// pass in whatever configuration parameters you need,
// like DB URL, etc.
func InitConfig() (*MyAppConfig, error) {
   // set up other configuration

   config := &MyAppConfig{
       // other config
       Logger: InitLogs(),
   }

   return config, nil
}

func (c *MyAppConfig) DoSomethingImportant() {
    c.Logger.Info("Hello")
}
```

Meanwhile, you can use this anywhere else, like in your CLI interface:

```
package main

import "utils"

...

func main() {
    // input, or CLI parameters...

    // pass in other CLI parameters, if any
    // (of course you'd have to change the function signature in
    // the previous file above)
    config, err := utils.NewConfig()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    config.DoSomethingImportant()

    // or since Logger is exported:
    config.Logger.Info("hello")
}
```

If you find you end up with lots of global things like the Logger you need to configure, the config struct is the more scalable approach IMO. As an added bonus, using a config type makes it easier to do dependency injection in unit tests than having the global variables used directly.

On the other hand, if you only have to worry about the one global Logger, then the config struct might be overkill, especially if it's not something you'll need to instrument when designing tests. It's a subjective call depending on your circumstances.

To answer your second question...

**Project Layout**

If `/server` has a main package with a command, move it under `cmd/server`.

Also, the way you currently have it, it would be a bit confusing for others to depend on your project. Since your repository appears to begin at `src/`, here's what it will look like when someone else tries to import your `utils` package:

File structure:

```
 <top of someone else's GOPATH>/
   src/
     myproject/src/utils/
       ...
```

To import:

```
 import "myproject/src/utils"
```

... and actually, since you `import "utils"` in your code right now, I don't think your code will compile in someone else's `GOPATH` because they don't have a `$GOPATH/src/utils`.

Solution: Your repository should not include `src/`. The idea is that you setup your `$GOPATH` and you put different repositories/packages inside of it. For example (assuming you host your code on Github):

```
 <top of gopath>/
   src/
     github.com/you/myproject/  <---- your repo starts here
       cmd/server/
         main.go
       utils
         file1.go
         logger.go
       handler
         handler1.go
         handler2.go
```

This would make your packages importable to you and to others like so:

```
import "github.com/you/myproject/utils"
```

Also, this project structure allow others to include your project inside their $GOPATH or in their `vendor/` interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks 1+, I think the idea which you describe as `Alternatively` sounds better, can you please provide example with my context for this ?

Comment: Added a simple example of a logger as a field in a config struct.

Comment: Thanks but Not sure what is related to what, the example you put is it related to main-> main and how should I use it from the handler ? it will be great if you can put the example in my context

Comment: Ok I added much more details about what I was trying to convey with the config struct. I also added an answer to the second part of your question about your project layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Now I really understand it. 2 validation question regard the project structure 1. what do you mean by `github.com/you/myproject/ ` your proj start here ? what is it ? 2. the handler and utils should be in the root project structure , do I get it right ? It will be great if you can share a real go project which have some best practice structure which explain your answer. thanks!

Comment: Replace `github.com/you/myproject` with the path to your package. The path you choose will be the path that everyone who depends on your project will import in their own code (and in the rest of your code as well). If your repository is hosted on GitHub, the convention is to set your package's path to `github.com/<username>/<reponame>` because that will work cleanly with go get... i.e. `go get github.com/you/project` would put your repository under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/you/project`. You can use whatever path you want, though, as long as you stick to it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use the exact logger from `main.go`. You should just export it and use it in other packages:

`server/main.go`

```
var Logger *logrus.Logger  // Notice capital L

func main() {
    Logger = utils.InitLogs()  // Init logger once
    ...
}
```

`handler/handler1.go`

```
import "server"

func run(){
   //here Im not using logger otherwise maybe I can move it as parameter…
} 

func build(){
    // No need to initialize logger as its done in main func.

    //Here Im using the logger
    server.Logger.info("in xyz")
}
```

And your project structure is not standard. See [this](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Thanks Arman, This is the best practice ? since here I create dependency on the main package...maybe yes just to verify since Im not expert in golang...

Comment: If you want to share same logger instance in you project, its better to move it into `utils/log.go` and `import "utils"` or even to its own package (If logging has more than just one variable and function)

Comment: Thanks but how I provide the instance to the `handler1` can you please provide example for this ? this is my main lack of understanding ....

Comment: just rename `logger` to `Logger` and import it. I changed my answer to be more like your question codes.